# What is the difference between a generic function and polymorphic argument types in scala?

Tags: scala

What is the difference between these two function declarations?

```
def fn[T <: A](t: T): Unit = ()

def fn(a: A): Unit = ()
```

Comment: Are you missing a generic `[A]` on the second function?

Comment: @Alec I think `A` is a type, not a type parameter.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov. Ah quite right. Else the first would not work either. :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: There certainly would be a difference if you returned `T` and `A` respectively instead of `Unit`. But in this case if there is any significant difference, I have no idea.

Comment: "What are you trying to achieve in the first place?" I'm reading code with the first function style, and I was trying to figure out why one would choose that style over the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 2 subtypes of `Universal` polymorphism: `Parametric` & `Inclusion` (inheritance/subtyping). They have own pros & cons, but **for this particular case** difference, what I can imagine, that for type polymorphism you will miss possibilities to overload functions (what is valuable part of inclusion polymorphism).

For example:

```
class A
class B // extends A // - if it is needed

class Foo {
  def fn(t: A): Unit = ()
  def fn(t: B): Unit = () // - is OK
}

class Boo {
  def fn[T <: A](t: T): Unit = ()
  def fn[T <: B](t: T): Unit = () // - is not OK (func names conflict)
}
```